# iOS 7 didEnterRegion not getting called at all

Tags: ios7, cllocationmanager, clregion, clcircleregion

I am using the following code to monitor for regions in my iOS app. It works perfectly when I build the app on iOS6. When I build it on iOS7, the didEnterRegion is not triggered.

// create and register a region with iOS

```
CLLocationCoordinate2D venueCenter = CLLocationCoordinate2DMake([favoriteVenue.venueLat      doubleValue], [favoriteVenue.venueLng doubleValue]);
CLRegion *region = [[CLRegion alloc] initCircularRegionWithCenter:venueCenter radius:REGION_RADIUS identifier:favoriteVenue.venueId];

AppDelegate *appDelegate = (AppDelegate*)[[UIApplication sharedApplication] delegate];
[appDelegate.locationManager startMonitoringForRegion:[self regionForVenue:favoriteVenue]];
```

// In the AppDelegate.m

```
- (void)locationManager:(CLLocationManager *)manager didEnterRegion:(CLRegion *)region
{
    NSLog(@"Entered region: %@", region.identifier);
}
```

I have also set the Required background modes as "App registers for location updates" in my plist files.

Any ideas of what is missing for this feature to work on iOS7?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Something that should work for both iOS 6 and 7 is to create a public method inside your class that conforms to `CLLocationManagerDelegate` protocol that tells itself to start monitoring the region.  For example:

```
//LocationManagerClass.h

@interface LocationManagerClass : NSObject

      {... other stuff in the interface file}

- (void)beginMonitoringRegion:(CLRegion *)region;

@end
```

and then in

```
//LocationManagerClass.m

@interface LocationManagerClass () <CLLocationManagerDelegate>
@end

@implementation LocationManagerClass

     {... other important stuff like locationManager:didEnterRegion:}

- (void)beginMonitoringRegion:(CLRegion *)region
{
    [[CLLocationManager sharedManager] startMonitoringForRegion:region];
}

@end
```

So in your case you would call `[appDelegate beginMonitoringRegion:region];`

On a side note, I would recommend NOT putting your location management code in the app delegate.  Although technically it will work it's not generally a good design pattern for things like this.  Instead as in the above example I would try putting it in it's own location manager class which will probably be a singleton.  This blog post gives some good support on why not to put tons of stuff in the app delegate: http://www.hollance.com/2012/02/dont-abuse-the-app-delegate/